# Weighted Random Sampling from 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random, sampling

I have a 2d numpy array Z and I want to randomly choose an index of Z where the chance of an index being chosen is proportional to the value of Z at that index.

Right now, I'm doing the following:

```
yar = list(np.ndenumerate(Z))
x,y = yar[np.random.choice(len(yar), p=Z.ravel()/Z.sum())][0]
```

Which does the job but feels hideous (and is extremely slow besides). Is there a better way?

Comment: Check out [Raymond Hettinger tweet](https://twitter.com/raymondh/status/748586729716719617) about wighted random, might be helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can optimize on avoiding the creation of `yar`. We would simply get the linear index equivalent from `np.random.choice`, convert it to the dimension indices with `np.unravel_index` to give us `x` and `y`.

So, the implementation would be -

```
linear_idx = np.random.choice(Z.size, p=Z.ravel()/float(Z.sum()))
x, y = np.unravel_index(linear_idx, Z.shape)
```

Just to give some context on the numbers by which the creation of `yar` was causing the bottleneck in that setup, here's a sample timing test -

```
In [402]: Z = np.random.randint(0,9,(300,400))

In [403]: yar = list(np.ndenumerate(Z))

In [404]: %timeit list(np.ndenumerate(Z))
10 loops, best of 3: 46.3 ms per loop

In [405]: %timeit yar[np.random.choice(len(yar), p=Z.ravel()/float(Z.sum()))][0]
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.34 ms per loop

In [406]: 46.3/(46.3+1.34)
Out[406]: 0.971872376154492
```

So, creating `yar` was *eating up* `97%` of the runtime there.